# Strange app behaviour after a test case fails - Robotium

Tags: android, junit, automated-tests, robotium

I have two Robotium test cases for my Android application.

When run separately, both tests finish successfully.
When run together, if the first test succeeds, the second one succeeds, too.

If I (intentionally) modify the first test so that an assertion fails, the second test fails too.

Both tests are really simple and exactly the same, except for one line that I added to the first test to make it fail: `assertTrue(false)`.

My Activity layout contains a sublayout that is `GONE` by default and becomes `VISIBLE` after loading data for activity is complete.
Test cases are then supposed to click on a view inside of that sublayout.

In the first test run, the sublayout appears.
In the second, it doesn't.
`Solo.waitForView(viewId)` returns true regardless.

`assertTrue(false)` is called **after** a click on the view is performed.

Why is failed assertion messing with subsequent test case executions?

Comment: Use Google's Espresso 2.0 that comes with the Android SDK.

Comment: I will give Espresso a try now, thanks.

Comment: Paste the test cases so we can see what you have done wrong.